# Equivalent function without using a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, map-function

What would be the equivalent of this without using a for loop?

Unsure what array method to use

```
function func(x){
    var y = [];
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        y.push(x[i]);
        y.push(x[i]);
    }
    return y;
}

var input = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

console.log(func(input));// returns [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
```

Comment: I'm sure the downvote is justified, but could I receive feedback for how to improve this question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there is no equivalent using `.map()` and a study of any basic description of how `.map()` works or even looking at how the MDN polyfill works would have shown you that there is no way to achieve this with `.map()`.  And, then you go and seem to like two answers that don't solve it with `.map()` alone.  It seems like you're really just asking for a cleaner way to accomplish your goal and should remove the `.map()` part from your question since it's a non-starter and apparently not a requirement either.

Comment: Makes sense thanks, edited the question to not specify the map function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot map directly, but you could reduce into a new expanded array:

```
arr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat([curr, curr]), []);
```

And this is without ES6 arrow function:

```
arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return prev.concat([curr, curr]); }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no one-to-one mapping between your two lists.  However, you could achieve the same with underscore e.g.:

```
_.flatten(_.map(input, function(item) {
  return [item, item];
}));
```

or

```
_.chain(input)
  .map(function(item) {
    return [item, item];
  })
  .flatten()
  .value();
```

Comment: Nice answer +1 for the underscore insight